# unable to play mp3 file in avplayer in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to play mp3 file using AVP player. But i couldn't play it..my code is

```
NSString *fileurl=[FILE_URL_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *parts = [fileurl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

NSLog(@"file name is %@",filename);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,filename];
//NSString* documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

NSString* foofile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSLog(@"foofile %@",foofile);
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
NSLog(@"boolean value is %hhd",fileExists);


if (fileExists)
{

    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSLog(@"existig url is%@",audioURL);

    NSData *urlData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
   // NSString *sourcePath =[audioURL path];
    //UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,filename];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:urlData  error:NULL];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

but i am unable to play that audio file....Please give your valuable solution.Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: add "[audioPlayer prepareToPlay]" before [audioPlayer play]

Answer (score 0):

You're currently appending documentsDirectory twice.

```
NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,filename];
//NSString* documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

NSString* foofile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

Once in filePath, and again in foofile.

Additionally, you seem to be doing a whole bunch of extra processing that you don't need to be doing. You should be able to create the audio player from the initial file url:

```
NSString *fileurl=[FILE_URL_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:fileUrl] error:&error];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: added [audioPlayer play]; but it doesnt work...just player window blinking and closing..

Comment: Updated answer. You seem to be doing a lot more work than you need to be doing. Just use the file url you have at the start to create the audioplayer.

Comment: NSString *fileurl=[FILE_URL_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [audioPlayer play];..i tried this also..but it didnt play anything....

Comment: audioURL should be `[NSURL urlWithString:fileUrl]`

Comment: NSString *fileurl=[FILE_URL_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileurl];
        NSLog(@"existig url is%@",audioURL);
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]        initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [audioPlayer play];....i tried like this also ....

Comment: Maybe the file url is invalid? What does it print?

Comment: Actually my concern is am unable to play ,what are the files recorded from my ipad device....

Comment: If the fileurl is incorrect then the AVAudioPlayer won't be able to play. Try creating an error object and passing it in when you create the player, then check if there is an error. I'll update my answer.